# Keep a thread running in a modal dialog c++ mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

So I open a modal dialog from my main dialog through `DoModal()`
Where should i put my thread function to keep it alive, can i put it in a constructor?. (The created dialog doesnt have any function like `OnInitDialog()` in my main dialog)

Comment: Thread function to keep **it** alive? Keep what alive? The modal dialog is alive because `DoModal` has not returned, and the main dialog is not active because a modal dialog is open.

Comment: i mean to keep the thread alive

Comment: Threads do not need to be kept alive. A thread runs until the main function of that thread returns. Threads can be _blocked_, when you make a blocking call though. And `DoModal` is _by design_ a blocking call.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AfxBeginThread to start thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinthread-class?view=vs-2019
and put it in oninitdialog like

```
BOOL CSimpleDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialog::OnInitDialog();

  // TODO: Add extra initialization here, like AfxBeginThread 
  m_cMyEdit.SetWindowText(_T("My Name")); // Initialize control values
  m_cMyList.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);          // Show or hide a control, etc.

  return TRUE; // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=vs-2019#oninitdialog

Comment: can i run the thread on my main dialog and its still running while the modal dialog is on ?

Comment: @MinhLêPhanCông: Very much **no**. Two hard reasons: the main dialog has a modal dialog open, and the main dialog is bound to the original thread.